# "You restarted/Computer restarted because of a problem" on wakeup, Evernote?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake, startup, error

For the last few days I've been getting scared because of these messages that appear very frequently on wakeup, and almost always when I wakeup after a long duration. Sometimes it says "you restarted your computer because of a problem" and others it says "computer restarted because of a problem".

The first time I had the chance to look at the report (not this one) I thought "oh well, happens", but since then I got it a few times, one time the computer wouldn't wakeup. Today I got it again and got the option to see the report so I've pasted it here. As you can see, and I'm not sure this says too much, but in the report it's written that: `BSD process name corresponding to current thread: EvernoteHelper`. Is it safe to say that EvernoteHelper is the cause? If not, what do I do?

Macbook Retina '13 2013 model running Yosemite. Recently installed Windows on Parallels.

**Update**: I've added, as recommended in comments, a screenshot of Console.log just before the Boot. The screenshot is right after the code dump. Thanks!

```
Thu Feb  5 11:12:17 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff801bc1a46e): Kernel trap at 0xffffff801b90e241, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff841adb6a04, CR3: 0x00000003fa2af09a, CR4: 0x00000000001627e0
RAX: 0x000000007b16d7b9, RBX: 0xffffff81b9ed3400, RCX: 0xffffff81b9ed3408, RDX: 0x0203030302020003
RSP: 0xffffff8203e7b5c0, RBP: 0xffffff8203e7b630, RSI: 0xffffff81b9ed3000, RDI: 0xffffff822e800b20
R8:  0xffffff841adb6a04, R9:  0xffffff8449ea75f4, R10: 0xffffff822e800c2c, R11: 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f
R12: 0xfffffec033e67000, R13: 0xffffff81b9ed3000, R14: 0xffffff805ca853b0, R15: 0x0000000000000001
RFL: 0x0000000000010206, RIP: 0xffffff801b90e241, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Fault CR2: 0xffffff841adb6a04, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x3

Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8203e7b270 : 0xffffff801bb2fe41 
0xffffff8203e7b2f0 : 0xffffff801bc1a46e 
0xffffff8203e7b4b0 : 0xffffff801bc36683 
0xffffff8203e7b4d0 : 0xffffff801b90e241 
0xffffff8203e7b630 : 0xffffff801bb931f1 
0xffffff8203e7b6a0 : 0xffffff801bb91d05 
0xffffff8203e7b6d0 : 0xffffff801bb942a1 
0xffffff8203e7b710 : 0xffffff801bb98ef8 
0xffffff8203e7b8c0 : 0xffffff801bb9d482 
0xffffff8203e7bae0 : 0xffffff801bc1a055 
0xffffff8203e7bca0 : 0xffffff801bc36683 
0xffffff8203e7bcc0 : 0xffffff801bc139a9 
0xffffff8203e7be20 : 0xffffff801bfb72a3 
0xffffff8203e7be80 : 0xffffff801bfb71af 
0xffffff8203e7beb0 : 0xffffff801bfb5f2d 
0xffffff8203e7bf70 : 0xffffff801bfb6074 
0xffffff8203e7bfb0 : 0xffffff801bc14dd7 

→ →BSD process name corresponding to current thread: EvernoteHelper

Mac OS version:
14C109

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0: Mon Dec 22 23:10:38 PST 2014; root:xnu-2782.10.72~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: DCF5C2D5-16AE-37F5-B2BE-ED127048DFF5
Kernel slide:     0x000000001b800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801ba00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801b900000
System model name: MacBookPro11,1 (Mac-189A3D4F975D5FFC)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 23022067733427
last loaded kext at 7956021739506: com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch    85.3 (addr 0xffffff7f9e291000, size 57344)
last unloaded kext at 230420547519: com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  2.0.55 (addr 0xffffff7f9db78000, size 36864)
loaded kexts:
com.parallels.kext.vnic 10.1.1 28614
com.parallels.kext.netbridge    10.1.1 28614
com.parallels.kext.hypervisor   10.1.1 28614
com.parallels.kext.usbconnect   10.1.1 28614
net.telestream.driver.TelestreamAudio   1.1.1
com.cyberic.SmoothMouse 9
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   4234
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   85.3
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.15.5
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.1.7d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   269.25
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.29.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   910.26.12
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  262.33.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 269.25
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 269.25
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.1d38
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.2f6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.2f6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.8.6
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.6
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.10.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   710.55
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 710.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
Model: MacBookPro11,1, BootROM MBP111.0138.B14, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.6 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.16f68
Graphics: Intel Iris, Intel Iris, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453120
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x31364B544631473634485A2D314736453120
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x112), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.159.13.12)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.2f6 15235, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0128F, 121.33 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.2
```

Console.log screenshot:
[image: console.log screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is happening whenever you have Evernote open it may be because it uses some function that could (**not** will) cause data corruption on the computer so OS X causes a kernel panic to protect its self. This function could be a old deprecated method Apple took out of the SDK during one of OS X updates.

To see if this is the issue either reinstall Evernote or delete it and see if that helps.

**Edit:**
If deleting the app works but not reinstalling you may need to wait for an update to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your console logs to see what happened before the computer restarted:

1. Launch `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`.
2. Select All Messages in the sidebar.
3. In the log pane, scroll up until you see a highlighted message that says

   > bootlog: BOOT_TIME ...
4. Scan the log entries before that to get an idea of the OS was going through before it panicked.

Comment: Thanks @ernest_bruce . I'm not really an expert on these matters, so I've attached a screenshot. Really hope it's not a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that whenI added "hola better internet" in my google chrome and enabled the extension it started the problem after sometimes. Then I again disabled the extension and I saw that problem is not occurring anymore

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! The OP does not appear to have your particular plugin installed, so it's difficult to say if this answer will help in solving the problem.